# Linear algebra derivative

Tags: vector-analysis

I have two given vectors $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and  $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I have the following application $f(X) = u^TXv $. I want to calculate its gradient w.r.t to X (which is supposed to be symmetric definite positive). So i did the following : $$u^TXv = trace(u^TXv)= trace((uv^T)^T X) $$Hence I get the following : $$\nabla f(X) = uv^T$$
But since $u^TXv= v^TXu$, I could also have obtained $$\nabla f(X) = vu^T $$

So what is the right answer ?

Comment: If you want to apply a symmetry constraint, take the unconstrained gradient $G=uv^T$ and generate the constrained gradient as $$G_c=G+G^T-{\rm Diag}(G)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convention you choosed for the gradient w.r.t. X need not to change once fixed . 
First you considered $\nabla_X f(X)=(\nabla_{x_{i,j}} f(X))_{i,j}$
and then you changed $\nabla_{X^T} f(X)=(\nabla_{x_{j,i}} f(X))_{i,j}$ .

Answer (score 0):

No this is not the answer. I supposed X to be symmetric. Read the whole problem. In fact we have : $\mathcal{A}_n$ and $S_n$ which are orthogonal complementary in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ hence :
$$trace(uv^TX)=trace((\frac{1}{2}(uv^T+vu^T)+\frac{1}{2}(uv^T-vu^T))X)=trace(\frac{1}{2}(uv^T+vu^T)X)$$
Because remember $\frac{1}{2}(uv^T-vu^T)$ belongs to $\mathcal{A}_n$  and $X$ belongs to $S_n$ hence the trace (which is the inner product is equal 0) hence the good answer was : 
$$\nabla f = \frac{1}{2}(uv^T+vu^T)$$